# iOS firmware Display with php

Tags: php, iphone

Is there a way to only display the iOS firmware in browser thru PHP?

I have tried this

```
echo $agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
```

but then al info is shown and i want only to display the iOS version. This is what i get if i use that code:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU OS X 7_0_2) AppleWebKit/536.30.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.5 mobile Safari/536.30.1 etc etc...
```

Is there any way to display this like: 7.0.2 only

Comment: You can find answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171895/detecting-ios-version-number-from-user-agent-using-regular-expressions

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php

$text =  $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]; 

preg_match('/OS X ([_0-9]+)/', $text, $res);

$version = isset($res[1])?str_replace('_','.',$res[1]):null;

var_dump($version);

/* EOF */
```

Comment: Thank you, id did exactly as descriped but for now i have an output like: string(5)"7.0.2" and i don't know for what reason "string(5)" is in the output.

Comment: You can also write echo $version; Than you get only the string, without information about the variable itself. See here: http://php.net/manual/de/function.var-dump.php