# Check if iOS version Compatiple from iOS 3.0 to IOS 4.0 or higher with PHP

Tags: javascript, php

this code is Only Check "This is iOS 10"

```
<?php
   if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'OS 10' ) !== false) {
     echo "This is iOS 10";
     }
      else {
        echo "This is not iOS 10";
     }
?>
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? What's the issue you want us to fix?

Comment: I want to have a Check, from iOS 10.0 to iOS 11.0

Comment: But what's the problem with the code you have right now?

Comment: No problems but an exampel of what i want

Comment: So if there's nothing wrong, why are you asking this question? ***What do you want us to fix?***

Comment: here 'OS 10' ,  i can not put 'OS 10.1 to 10.6'

Comment: and Sorry for the delay in reply because I do not speak English

Comment: I'm translating on Google

Comment: What? What do you mean "you're translating"?

Comment: I do not mean bad ,
I speak Arabic only, I do not speak English, so I take the time to translate from Arabic to English

Comment: But the code you have there seems to work. ***What is the problem you want us to solve?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still have a problem with ios version number, you can use regex. [Detecting iOS Version Number from User Agent using Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171895/detecting-ios-version-number-from-user-agent-using-regular-expressions)